# Installing from PyPI fails with unsatisfiable version, but those exist in PyPI when installing them manually

Tags: python, pypi

I encounter some weird behavior when trying to install my package from PyPI.

When I run

```
pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ simple-api==0.0.0.0.5
```

it fails with

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement singledispatch>=3.4.0.3 (from graphene-django->simple-api==0.0.0.0.5) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for singledispatch>=3.4.0.3 (from graphene-django->simple-api==0.0.0.0.5)
```

However, when I then run `pip install singledispatch>=3.4.0.3`, suddenly there is no problem with the version requirement. After I fix a few more packages manually this way, pip installs my package no problem.

The possibly relevant part of `setup.py`:

```
install_requires=[
    "django",
    "graphene",
    "graphene-django",
],
```

Does anyone have an idea what the problem might be? Should any more information be needed, let me please know in the comments, I will edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like some "production" packages aren't uploaded to the Test Index `https://test.pypi.org/`.

If you want to *add* an extra package index, use `--extra-index-url` instead of `-i`:

```
pip install --extra-index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/ simple-api==0.0.0.0.5
```

Comment: Wow, it indeed worked just like that! Next time I should not just copypaste from tutorials probably. Thank you!